# Function to remove directory removes it only after debug finishes c++

Tags: c++, debugging, directory

I have this code in c++ to remove directory that includes files in it:

```
void*  hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;

        hFind = FindFirstFile((fullpath+"\\" + _docname + "\\"+"*").c_str(), &ffd);

        do //delete all the files in the directory
        {
            // check if it is a file
            if (!(ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
            {
                string s = (fullpath+_docname+"\\").append(ffd.cFileName);
                remove(s.c_str());
            }
        }
        while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
        removeDirectory(fullpath+"\\" + _docname);      
        FindClose(hFind);
```

The problem is - the directory is actually removed only after I close the dubugger.
While debugging, the directory is inaccessible, but still exists, and it make me troubles.
Do you know how can I fix it to tottaly remove the folder?

Comment: Shouldn't you be closing the find before removing the directory?

Comment: I tried that, it didn't worked...any other idea?

Comment: what line exactly do you mean with 'while debugging' ?

Comment: I mean the after the line "removeDirectory..."

Answer (score 4):

swapping the last two lines might fix this: close the handle before removing the directory

```
FindClose( hFind );
removeDirectory( fullpath + "\\" + _docname );
```

Comment: It removes the directory - makes it inaccessible - but it still exist..I don't know how to fix it..

Comment: strange.. the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365488(v=vs.85).aspx) clearly says "The RemoveDirectory function marks a directory for deletion on close. Therefore, the directory is not removed until the last handle to the directory is closed" (and also "To recursively delete the files in a directory, use the `SHFileOperation` function." so I would give that a try instead

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I had to look in the whole project to see if the file was open in another place. I closed it, and now it works.